# JTextPane does not display correct foreground color

Tags: java, swing, colors, jtextpane

want to have a JTextPane whose content can always be selected by the user. Therefore I created my own subclass of JTextPane and always return true in the method "isEnabled()". Additionally I introduce a new member m_enabled which is responsible for returning the correct foreground color (enabled/disabled)

```
public class StylesExample1 {
public static final String text = "Lorem ipsum dolor...";
public static boolean m_enabled = true;

public static void main(String[] args) throws BadLocationException {
    try {
        UIManager.setLookAndFeel("com.sun.java.swing.plaf.windows.WindowsLookAndFeel");
    } catch (Exception evt) {
    }

    JFrame f = new JFrame("Frame");
    final JTextPane pane = new MyPane();
    pane.setText(text);

    pane.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(200, 200));
    f.getContentPane().add(pane);
    JButton b = new JButton("Toggle Enabled state");
    b.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            m_enabled = !m_enabled;
            System.err.println("setting textpane enabled to " + m_enabled);
            pane.setEnabled(m_enabled);
        }
    });
    f.getContentPane().add(b);
    f.getContentPane().setLayout(new FlowLayout());
    f.setSize(400, 300);
    f.setVisible(true);
}
}

class MyPane extends JTextPane {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
private boolean m_enabled = true;

public void setEnabled(boolean enabled) {
    m_enabled = enabled;
}

@Override
public Color getForeground() {
    if (m_enabled) {
        System.err.println("foreground color: " + super.getForeground());
        return super.getForeground();
    } else {
        System.err.println("foreground color: " + getDisabledTextColor());
        return getDisabledTextColor();
    }
}

@Override
public boolean isEnabled() {
    return true;
}
}
```

The Problem now is that the foreground color does not change. It always looks as the textpane is disabled. However the debug information in "getForeground" say the following

```
setting textpane enabled to true
foreground color: javax.swing.plaf.ColorUIResource[r=0,g=0,b=0]
setting textpane enabled to false
foreground color: javax.swing.plaf.ColorUIResource[r=109,g=109,b=109]
```

This looks okay to me, but the textpane always looks diabled[image]

Do you have any ideas?

Comment: Click button third time and you will find it `foreground color: javax.swing.plaf.ColorUIResource[r=109,g=109,b=109]` for all subsequent clicks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`super.getForeground()` is returning disabled color in the next call because once you set it to disabled color it will propagate to super class also as shown below:

Here is code directly from `JComponent`

```
public void setForeground(Color fg) {
    Color oldFg = getForeground();
super.setForeground(fg);
if ((oldFg != null) ? !oldFg.equals(fg) : ((fg != null) && !fg.equals(oldFg))) {
    // foreground already bound in AWT1.2
    repaint();
}
}
```

---

> No need to override getForeground() method just call setForeground() method form setEnabled() method.

Store default foreground color somewhere before updating and use it in further calls.

Can you try this one

```
class MyPane extends JTextPane {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private boolean m_enabled = true;
    private Color defaultForegroundColor, disabledTextColor;

    public MyPane() {
        defaultForegroundColor = getForeground();
        disabledTextColor = getDisabledTextColor();
    }

    public void setEnabled(boolean enabled) {
        m_enabled = enabled;

        if (m_enabled) {
            setForeground(defaultForegroundColor);
        } else {
            setForeground(disabledTextColor);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isEnabled() {
        return true;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you're missing a `repaint()` call in your `ActionListener`. I can't tell more, as you don't have the code for your MyPane class available :)